# How to match the contents of two arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, set, containers

I have two separate arrays of words, for example:

```
array1 = word1, word2, word3
array2 = word4, word5, word6
```

I am trying to match the two arrays based on user input (which will be 2 words). 
For example, you input "word1 word6", and the program gives you x. You input "word3 word4" and the program gives you y. There doesn't need to be/shouldn't be matching within each of the arrays (so entering "word1 word3" should not be giving anything other than an error).

Now, I was thinking of using `string::find` to look for the contents of each array in the input string. However, after that I'm stuck on how to take these results (if any) and match them against each other.

For example, I would `input.find(contents of array1)`, and if something is found, take that `array1[x]`, and see if the combination with `array2[x]` found through a separate line in the same input matches a third list of possible combinations. If it does I would then split the response based on which combo it is.

I know it would be easier if I just had a list of possible matches, and found *that* in the input string. But I wanted to keep the two sets of words separate as the code would be more flexible (and I would learn more this way).

Hopefully someone can give me some tips on how to proceed?

Comment: I don't understand what 'x' means when you say "For example, you input "word1 word6", and the program gives you x". Same issue for the next sentence :)

Comment: Do you meant WORD which is unsigned short?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a general result - in this case I would probably execute some functions based on which set of two words the user has entered.

Comment: At first you wrote "arrays", then you wrote about creating a temporary "list" and at the end you write about "two sets of words". Note that these are 3 different types of containers.

Comment: I am actually a bit confused about the difference between, say, arrays and vectors. All I need is a "list" (dictionary definition, not C++ type :P) of words. I would use a vector for this but the friend who inspired me for this "exercise" mentioned arrays so I figured it would be possible with them, too. Really sorry for the confusion, as I said I am new to this so I might using C++ terminology without meaning to!

Answer (score 5):

C++ has a special structure for this kind of problem and it's called "map"

```
typedef std::map< std::pair< std::string, std:: string >, int > MyMapType;
MyMapType my_map;
```

Above is for example a map that given a pair of strings returns an int. Of course not all possible pairs of strings need to be included in the map:

```
my_map[std::make_pair("A", "B")] = 42;
my_map[std::make_pair("A", "C")] = 99;
my_map[std::make_pair("B", "D")] = 103;
```

To see if a specific pair is present you can use `map::find`:

```
MyMapType::iterator i = my_map.find(std::make_pair(x, y));
if (i == my_map.end()) {
    std::cout << "Pair is not defined\n";
} else {
    // Pair is present
    std::cout << "Associated value is " << *i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Since based on the additional comments of OP, this is actually what he was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the easiest option be to use [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to get the common elements. You do need sorted inputs though.

```
  int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
  int second[] = {50,40,30,20,10};

  it=std::set_intersection (first, first+5, second, second+5, v.begin());
```

Will result in a vector with 20 elements in it: 10 and 20. (as per the link).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand:

- you have 2 sets of words,
- 2 words from the user and
- you want to find out if those 2 words are contained in these sets but not from the same set

Then you might do something like:

```
inline const bool isIn(const std::set<std::word>& s, const std::string& e) {
    return s.find(e) != s.end();
}

...

std::set<std::string> wordSet1, wordSet2;
std::string word1, word2; // <-- from the user
...
if (isIn(wordSet1, word1) && isIn(wordSet2, word2)) {
    // success
}
else if (isIn(wordSet2, word1) && isIn(wordSet1, word2) {
    // success
}
else {
    // fail
}
```

but since complexity of `std::set::find` is O(log n) and this approach calls it 4 times, it is not very effective one. Also note that if order is well defined, i.e. `word1` must be from `wordSet1` and `word2` must be from `wordSet2`, the second condition (`else if`) should be omitted.

And in case the order is well defined and you need to look for these pairs multiple times, then creating a temporary `std::set< std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` with all possible combinations might be more reasonable approach, but since you wrote: *"I know it would be easier if I just had a list of possible matches... But I wanted to keep the two sets of words separate "*, that's probably not what you are looking for.

I hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Store your words however you like and put the combinations that are searchable in a bloom filter.

Pseudo Code of the most general form...:

Inserting:

> ```
> for words in wordArray:
>     bloomFilter.add( words.hash() )
> ```

Searching:

> ```
> found = false
> if bloomFilter.contains( searchedForWords.hash() ):
>     if originalWordList.contains( words )
>         found = true
> ```

Some notes about a bloom filter:

1. It is very fast to look something up.
2. Use a good, fast hash function.  There are tons on the internet
3. It can generate a false positive (X is in the filter when it actually is not)
4. It cannot generate a false negative (X is not in the filter)
5. When the bloom filter says something is in the filter, you have to look in the original source data to make sure it is actually there.

I used this method with an application firewall that was built to keep porn and the related crap off the network and it sped that particular code up over 400 times versus storing in a traditional map or hash table.